Copy specific fields to another sheet
I would like to do this:

From a Google form, some fields are filled in and then written in a Google sheet (SOURCE)
I attach an image:


I would like that for each new row created in the sheet (Source), some data is copied to another Google sheet in the first free row
But only some fields of the sheet (source) and in some specific cells.
I attach an image:



I start from this code, which works, but it copies all the fields.
function copyPaste() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx");
 var source = ss.getSheetByName("New_Customers");
 var rangeSource = source.getDataRange();
 var data = rangeSource.getValues();
 var lr = rangeSource.getLastRow();
 var lc = rangeSource.getLastColumn();
 Logger.log(data);


 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx");
 var target = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
 target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1,1,lr,lc).setValues(data);
 }


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, provide a minimal, reproducible example using Tables or tools like Table to Markdown that can easily be copied and pasted. If necessary, and as a last resort, Make an anonymous sample document.

@Saddles Who crafted this new one without email address?

Hi, @TheMaster, I believe it's created by Lance.NYC, one of Google's Product Experts. SHEETS Product Experts' – TIPS FOR POSTING

Copy and paste specific columns from different sheets
In order to filter the different columns that you wanted to copy from one sheet to another. you can try the below code:
Complete code:
function copyPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx");
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("New_Customers");
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx");
  var target = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var targetRow = target.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  var values = source.getRange(source.getLastRow(), 1, 1, source.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  //getting the values form `New_Customers` sheet
  var bval = values[0][1];
  var cval = values[0][2];
  var eval = values[0][5];
  var gval = values[0][7];
  var dval = values[0][3];

  //setting the values to `Sheet1` sheet
  target.getRange(targetRow, 1).setValue(bval);
  target.getRange(targetRow, 2).setValue(cval);
  target.getRange(targetRow, 3).setValue(eval);
  target.getRange(targetRow, 5).setValue(gval);
  target.getRange(targetRow, 11).setValue(dval);
}

NOTE: this has some limitations when it comes to runtime since you are using multiple getRange() and setValue()
As an alternative approach for this, you can replace the code below the //setting the values to improve runtime but it will set an empty values to the other columns between them, which is its limitation when you already have values within the empty ranges (e.g. image, and Giomi dall'ultimo compleanno columns of target sheet) before submitting the form:
Alternative setting the values:
  var values = [[bval, cval, eval, "", gval, "", "", "", "", "", dval]];
  target.getRange(targetRow, 2, 1, 11).setValues(values);  

Please do not forget to add an On Form Submit Installable trigger so that every value submitted will be copied automatically to the other sheets.
Sample output:

NOTE: The values and ranges are only for the demo purposes on how the code works
Additional/Some improvements:
If you only have one spreadsheet for this project, you can easily use the  getActiveSpreadsheet() and maximize the getSheetByName() to minimize the runtime issue.
Instead of:
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx");
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("New_Customers");
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx");
  var target = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

You can use:
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("New_Customers");
  var target = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

References:

getRange(row, column)
getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)


Updated
Here is one way you could go about this:
 function copyPaste() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx");
 var source = ss.getSheetByName("New_Customers");
 var lr = source.getLastRow();
 var colB = source.getRange(lr,2).getValues();
 var colC = source.getRange(lr,3).getValues();
 var colE = source.getRange(lr,5).getValues();
 var colG = source.getRange(lr,7).getValues();
 var colD = source.getRange(lr,4).getValues();
 var data = [colB,colC,colE,,colG,,,,,,colD];

 const colArray = data[0].map((_, i) => data.map(row => row[i]));


 Logger.log(data);


 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx");
 var target = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var tlr = target.getLastRow()+1;

 target.getRange(tlr,1,1,11).setValues(colArray);
 }

Basing this answer on your current script and the information I could derive from your screenshot, this script will copy the data in the last row of Columns B, C, E, G, and D and paste it to the last row of Columns A,B,C,E, and K in the target sheet.  It will paste "null" values in the columns in between.
One word of warning, if this is a form that is used by multiple users, possibly at the same time, you may not get the expected row correctly with getLastRow(), in which case it would be better to use the onFormSubmit() trigger and capture the event passed to that trigger and then extract the columns needed.  But I based this answer based on the manner in which you were trying to pass the data from one spreadsheet to the other.

function copyPaste() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxx");
 var sh = ss.getSheetByName("New_Customers");
 const [[a,b,c,,e,,g]] = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx");
 var target = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
 target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1,1,1,5).setValues([[a,b,c,e,g]]);
 }

